# Magento webserver temporary report lost mysq connection with error code 4 in 1-2 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, magento, nginx

Currently,I am using two servers :webserver with magento 1.7,nginx ,php-fpm,redis for cache ,and one mysql db server with version 5.5.32.
And sometimes which continued occured in 1-2 minutes ,the webserver report error :
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'remoteserverip' (4)  on lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96) .
But I check it with mysql command to connect remote db server,it is ok.
I searched on google and stackoverflow,there is no such problem reported.

As I see ,the two servers' cpu and memory are not overload,and the http 80 connection are about 500 .
I also change the webserver :

```
# cat /etc/sysctl.conf 
# System default settings live in /usr/lib/sysctl.d/00-system.conf.
# To override those settings, enter new settings here, or in an /etc/sysctl.d/<name>.conf file
#
# For more information, see sysctl.conf(5) and sysctl.d(5).

# Disable IPv6 autoconf 
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra = 0


#file.file-max = 20000000
fs.file-max = 20000000
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
#net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 30
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 15
#net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 1200
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 120
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 30
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 6

net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 8192
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 5000

vm.overcommit_memory = 1
net.core.somaxconn = 3096
```

And nginx setting:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  32;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;

events {
    worker_connections  65535;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';


    access_log off;
    server_tokens off;

        #Adjust client timeouts
        #client_max_body_size 50M;
        client_body_buffer_size 20k;
        client_body_timeout 12;
        client_header_timeout 12;
        keepalive_timeout 30;
        send_timeout 10;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;

        #Adjust output buffers
        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 3s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        server_names_hash_bucket_size 100;



    gzip on;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length 1100; 
    #gzip_buffers 16 8k; 
    gzip_buffers 4 32k;   
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level 6; 
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_vary on;
    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    open_file_cache max=5000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors off; 
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

for DB server :

```
# cat /etc/sysctl.conf 
# Kernel sysctl configuration file for Red Hat Linux
#
# For binary values, 0 is disabled, 1 is enabled.  See sysctl(8) and
# sysctl.conf(5) for more details.

# Controls IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0

# Controls source route verification
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1

# Do not accept source routing
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0

# Controls the System Request debugging functionality of the kernel
kernel.sysrq = 0

# Controls whether core dumps will append the PID to the core filename.
# Useful for debugging multi-threaded applications.
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1

# Controls the use of TCP syncookies
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

# Disable netfilter on bridges.
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0

# Controls the default maxmimum size of a mesage queue
kernel.msgmnb = 65536

# Controls the maximum size of a message, in bytes
kernel.msgmax = 65536

# Controls the maximum shared segment size, in bytes
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736

# Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages
kernel.shmall = 4294967296

# Disable IPv6 autoconf 
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra = 0
fs.file-max = 200000

# Increase system IP port limits to allow for more connections

net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65000

#net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 0

# number of packets to keep in backlog before the kernel starts dropping them 
#net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 1280

# increase socket listen backlog
#net.core.somaxconn = 3240000
#net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000

# Increase TCP buffer sizes
#net.core.rmem_default = 8388608
#net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
#net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
#net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
#net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216
#net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = cubic

#Solve TIME_WAIT
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 30
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 1200
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 8192
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 5000
```

and mysql connection_timeout :

```
mysql> show variables like "%conn%";
+--------------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name            | Value           |
+--------------------------+-----------------+
| character_set_connection | utf8            |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci |
| connect_timeout          | 60              |
| init_connect             |                 |
| max_connect_errors       | 10              |
| max_connections          | 14000           |
| max_user_connections     | 0               |
+--------------------------+-----------------+
```

Firstly,I thought it was the db server unstable,but the mysql remote command connect is ok,just the php mysql_connect report lost connection.
And I also changed some net.ipv4 variables of sysctl ,but not work.
Could you some one tell me how to track such problem?
Is there any other tuning for mysql and webserver settings.
Thanks in advance.